# Customizing Powershell to look like Github for Windows' shell

Tags: windows, shell, git, powershell, github

I use [Github for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) and usually I use the "Open a Shell" here command which launches powershell with some custom settings. It makes powershell display extra information when I'm inside a Git repo like the status of the Repo just before the prompt, having a black background...

However when I use the normal powershell, all those niceties are gone. I would like those changes on the powershell to become the default so that I wouldn't have to launch the custom prompt.

I was wondering if its possible to get those settings at runtime and then apply it permanently. I have been able to make powershell have a black background by default and change the default font but I can't get those extra info on git repositories.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different default places the Powershell profile can be stored.  This is where your custom code should be stored, so that every time you open up a new Powershell prompt it applies these settings.

The first location is the global location and would be useful when you want all users to have a customized Powershell profile. This profile should be placed in **C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Profile.ps1**.

The second location is for the local profile and would be specific to each user account. This file overrides the global configuration file and should be placed in **C:\Username\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1**.

As for getting your git stuff working, there are some good blog posts [here](http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2009/08/21/using-git-and-everything-else-through-powershell/) and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/13/better-git-with-powershell.aspx) that go over how to customize the profile to make git work better and look pretty.  Select the parts of their code/configuration to your own profile to get your git settings up and working the way you want.

Comment: Thanks.. The second post was exactly what I needed. Turns out Phil Haack is the guy who developed Git for Windows. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Glad to hear it works :)

Answer (score 4):

GitHub for Windows uses Posh-Git. You should get it from GitHub (https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) and add it to your regular profile, which lives at `$PROFILE`, using something like:

```
git clone https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git ~\GitHub\posh-git
'Import-Module ~\GitHub\posh-git\posh-git' >> $PROFILE
```